# The JSON string sequence differs from my JSON class,Please Suggest me how to Correct the Sequence

Tags: json, format

Getting below JSON Format where the sequence of the tags are wrong. how can i change the sequence of the JSON?

```
{ 
   "HoldingRequest":{ 
      "HoldingData":[ 
         { 
            "dmat":"IN30051314972576",
            "accountType":"CLNTBENE",
            "action":null
         },
         { 
            "dmat":"IN30051314972576",
            "accountType":"CLNTBENE",
            "action":null
         },
         { 
            "dmat":"IN30051314972576",
            "accountType":"CLNTBENE",
            "action":null
         }
      ],  
      "memberPan":"AAECS5096H",
      "date":"20190914"
   }
}
```

First three tags are placed at the end, but I want memberPan, date at the start

```
//Below is my class 

    public class JHoldingRequest
    {
        public JHoldingReqHeader HoldingRequest;   

        public class JHoldingReqHeader
        {
            public string memberPan { get; set; }
            public string Date { get; set; }
            public List<JHoldingReqDataList> HoldingData;        
        }
        public class JHoldingReqDataList
        {
            public string dmat { get; set; }
            public string accountType { get; set; }
            public string action { get; set; }

        }  
    }

    ///
    Serializing
    string json = string.Empty;
    JNilHoldingRequest.JNilHoldingReqHeader objheader = new  JNilHoldingRequest.JNilHoldingReqHeader();
    json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objheader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, objects in Javascript (JavaScriptSerializer()) don't respect order.
If order is important, you need to work with arrays.